# Document storage in phpmyadmin vs website folder?

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, phpmyadmin, document

What is the best way to store documents that saves space? By letting user documents to be stored in phpmyadmin db or by creating folders and letting user upload documents there?

I want to allow scans like pdf and images and also word docs and .txt files.

Also, how will i go about uploading documents? Any tutorials i can use?  New to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpmyadmin, is an script that lets you edit\add\etc mysql db's its not a db. Depending on the type of documents, and what you plan to do with them I would always say store them in the file system, you can store there name\path in the db.

file upload tutorial: [Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: So you are saying is should create a pth on my website like domain.com/account/user/documents/document.pdf

Comment: yes, if you need them secure, create the folder under the web root.